# WordPress not displaying information on post sent from custom admin form

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I want to create my own plugin in which you enter information in the admin panel and that information is displayed on your page.
So far i have created a new admin menu with a form but it is not sending the information to my website. Please give me a hand.

```
 <?php

/*

Plugin Name: newsSlider-Plugin

*/

print_r($_SESSION);

add_action("admin_menu", "addMenu");

function addMenu()

{

    add_menu_page("News slider", "News slider", 5, "subMenu", "changeTextFunction");

    add_submenu_page("subMenu", "change style", "change style", 5, "changeStyle", 
"changeStyleFunction");

}

function changeTextFunction()

{

    echo "Write down the news you want to be displayed in the fields";

    echo '

    <form method="post" action="">

    News field 1<input type="text" name="newsSlide1">

    News field 2<input type="text" name="newsSlide2">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

    </form>';

    echo $_SESSION["favcolor"];

}

function changeStyleFunction()

{

    echo "subsmenu hellooo";

}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$newsSliderInput1= test_input($_POST["newsSlide1"]);

session_start();

$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "yellow";

}

function test_input($data) {

  $data = trim($data);

  $data = stripslashes($data);

  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

  return $data;

}

add_action("the_content", "displayNewsSlider");

function displayNewsSlider()

{

    echo $newsSliderInput1;

    echo "hi";

    echo $_SESSION["favcolor"];

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input needs to be saved somewhere, so it can be retrieved when a user visits the website. To achieve this you could for example use the `update_option()` and `get_option()` functions from the [WordPress Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) to store the values.

To store the value:

```
function changeStyleFunction() {
    update_option( 'newsSlide1', test_input($_POST["newsSlide1"]) );
}
```

To retrieve the value:

```
function displayNewsSlider() {
    echo get_option( 'newsSlide1', '' );
}
```